# Downloading files using Chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, script, download

I'm new to this (and i don't speak English).

I want to download a bunch of mp4-files, I know the location of each file but I don't want to open and "right-click-save-as" for each file. Is there a way to download the files using the console built into Google Chrome?

Let's say the location of the file is `http://www.google.com/movies/test.mp4`.
What's the command for downloading that file immediately?

Comment: why not get wget or some other cli tool - you can even give wget a list of links and get it to download all of them, IIRC

Comment: Thanks, I used while read line; do curl -O "$line"; done < urls.txt